# Blue box around profile page items

Tags: discussion, profile-page, responsive-design, mobile-chrome, action-buttons

When clicking on a tab of my profile page, this blue rectangular box flashes around it, which is rather ugly compared to the buttons with the nice rounded angles.

I can't recall duplicating this on a computer.
[image]

Is this an artefact of something, or should I turn this into a bug report?

Comment: Either way I think it needs to be changed, since the contrast is so poor

Comment: @Laurel, I don't think it is actually a feature, so no need on improving that.

Comment: What OS/Browser are you on? I can't reproduce on Chrome on macOS 10.15.3. I suspect it is a browser specific thing for "active" links.

Comment: Chrome on android @KodosJohnson

Comment: I repro'd on my phone but it just flashes on for a split-second. It doesn't stay on like your screenshot.

Comment: Same here @KodosJohnson , I improved the wording. Took me about 10 tries to capture ;)

Comment: I can't repro in Chrome / Win 10. All userscripts off.

Comment: Neither can I @rene. Appears to be a mobile (chrome) thing..

Comment: The "tabs" are actually links, so they behave like default links on the mobile browsers.  Active links you touch or touch and hold are highlighted blue to confirm to the user they are clicking a link by mobile Chrome.  Happens on all links across all sites that don't modify the behavior.  Of note it is possible to remove it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003535/anyway-to-prevent-the-blue-highlighting-of-elements-in-chrome-when-clicking-quic

Comment: Thx @RageFoxx, clear explanation. I think we could safely disable it, as there is already CSS that highlights the buttons you select, for non-mobile use.

Answer (score 3):

That is a CSS button focus outline. It helps the user when they are using keyboards 'Tab' key to navigate the page. I see no necessary reason to remove it.

For more information please do visit: [outlinenone.com](http://www.outlinenone.com/) here it is explained why this feature is necessary and important

Comment: Thinking some more about this, it is kind of redundant, as the button you click also changes colour. So the information is already conveyed.

Comment: It is not about "clicking" it is trying to tell where you have reached when you are not able to use a mouse or use the touchscreen features and have to navigate the webpage using the keyboard and mobile keypad.